# How to post button value to label field using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using AJAX to post a button value to `<label>` but it is not working. It is not displaying anything in alert as well. I want to post on same page

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  


     $(".get_time").click(function () {
      var timeid = $(this).data('id');

       $.ajax({


         method='post',
         url: MainPage.aspx,
         dataType: "json",
         data: { id: timeid },
         success: function (data) {
             var dt = $('#View').html(data);
             alert(dt);
             document.getElementById("View").innerHTML = $('#View').html(data);;
         

         },
         error: function (err) {

         }
     });

     });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you share your html part as well?

Comment: It looks you're using class selector not id. Sharing full html and also code behind can help to answer for your problem

Comment: The ' url: MainPage.aspx' is incorrect. It should be within single quotes followed by your page name like this:  url: 'MainPage.aspx/YourPageName'. Also you are passing JSON format so the data should be like data: JSON.stringify({id:imeid})

Comment: Still not working